# Python selenium não realiza a função send_keys

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automatização

Estou tentando fazer um bot que comente sozinho em video do youtube, ele está funcionando normalmente, até chegar na hora de digitar o comentário. Já pesquisei em tudo que é lugar e não achei nada que me ajuda com isso. Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço. Segue o código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


class botComentario:
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/dev/chromedriver')
    self.username = "email"
    self.senha = "senha"
    self.comentario = "comentario"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    options.add_argument('lang=pt-br')

def acessarPagina(self):
    self.driver.get('http://www.youtube.com.br')
    time.sleep(3)
    login = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="buttons"]/ytd-button-renderer/a')
    time.sleep(1)
    login.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    logar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]')
    time.sleep(1)
    logar.click()
    logar.send_keys(self.username)
    conectar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/span')
    conectar.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    senha = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
    time.sleep(1)
    senha.click()
    senha.send_keys(self.senha)
    time.sleep(1)
    conectar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/span')
    conectar.click()
    self.driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWmuR5H4PlU')
    time.sleep(3)
    login = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="buttons"]/ytd-button-renderer/a')
    login.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 4000)")
    time.sleep(5)

    sessao = 0
    while sessao == 0:
        time.sleep(5)
        comentario = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="simplebox-placeholder"]')
        self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('simplebox-placeholder').click()")
        comentario.send_keys(self.comentario)
        time.sleep(5)
        time.sleep(2)
        btncoment = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submit-button"]/a')
        time.sleep(3)
        btncoment.click()




 bot = botComentario()
 bot.acessarPagina()
```

**Ele retorna o seguinte erro:** 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "botcomentador.py", line 60, in 
    bot.acessarPagina()
  File "botcomentador.py", line 49, in acessarPagina
    comentario.send_keys(self.comentario)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webel
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  *File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webel
, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable*
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.92)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?

O seu código tem alguns erros e vamos comentar eles agora.

O primeiro erro crucial no seu código é tentar clicar e enviar as keys, quando você faz o clique na box de comentário o estado muda e com isso já não é mais inidentificável onde seria enviado as keys da função send keys.

O segundo erro do código é seu scrollTo exagerado fazendo o carregamento de objetos desnecessário na página.

O terceiro que não é bem um erro, é como você está fazendo o login, fazendo o login diretamente na página do youtube em navegadores mais atualizados não é possível, então estou passando uma outra maneira de fazer esse login antes de ir para o vídeo em si, deixando seu código mais compatível de ser executado em outros locais.

E por último utilizar o sleep da biblioteca time não é muito indicado visto que você pode ter diferentes tempos de respostas, dependendo da velocidade da internet e do processamento por exemplo. O certo seria você fazer verificações na árvore DOM e comparando URL'S em alguns casos, deixaria mais performático e diminuiria a chance do código quebrar. Em último caso eu não recomendaria mas você também pode fazer uso de loops com try e except.

vamos logo ao código final.

o código ficou assim:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


class botComentario:
    def __init__(self):        
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('lang=pt-br')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='g:\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
        self.username = "email"
        self.senha = "senha"
        self.comentario = "comentário"

    def logarConta(self):
        self.driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/identifier?client_id=717762328687-iludtf96g1hinl76e4lc1b9a82g457nn.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=profile%20email&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fstackauth.com%2Fauth%2Foauth2%2Fgoogle&state=%7B%22sid%22%3A526%2C%22st%22%3A%2259%3A3%3ABBC%2C16%3Ac3b339248cd15a98%2C10%3A1586882568%2C16%3A6523c4245b21192c%2C9be2dd9be623e3715fe47acbbc4fa7378cc9971848446578e27189dad062ea94%22%2C%22cdl%22%3Anull%2C%22cid%22%3A%22717762328687-iludtf96g1hinl76e4lc1b9a82g457nn.apps.googleusercontent.com%22%2C%22k%22%3A%22Google%22%2C%22ses%22%3A%227a0b075d423241f8bbcd97564752ce4b%22%7D&response_type=code&o2v=1&as=hX0j6XjfZGPt3PSNBNuS2A&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow')
        time.sleep(3)
        logar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]')
        time.sleep(1)
        logar.click()
        logar.send_keys(self.username)
        conectar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/span')
        conectar.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        senha = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
        time.sleep(1)
        senha.click()
        senha.send_keys(self.senha)
        time.sleep(1)
        conectar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/span')
        conectar.click()

    def acessarPagina(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        self.driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R288k4p6ZkU')
        time.sleep(5)
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 500)")
        time.sleep(5)
        selecionarCampo = self.driver.find_element_by_id('placeholder-area')
        selecionarCampo.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        inputTexto = self.driver.find_element_by_id('contenteditable-root')
        inputTexto.send_keys(self.comentario)
        buttonEnviar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submit-button"]')
        buttonEnviar.click()


bot = botComentario()
bot.logarConta()
bot.acessarPagina()
```

Comment: Valeu mano ajudou muito, sou novo no Python e to curtindo muito a linguagem, da pra fazer muita coisa com ela.

Comment: Continue é uma excelente linguagem e bons estudos.